# How to avoid duplicate pages?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Assume the following. We have a taxonomic vocabulary called **product**. Which contains two terms: **tables** and **chairs**. This taxonomy creates the following URL's:

- http://www.mydomain.me/product/tables
- http://www.mydomain.me/product/chairs

[Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module to create a menu that taxonomy. If we click the *Tables* menu item leads to *http://www.mydomain.me/product/tables*. Which shows a list of all published tables. Same with the chairs.

All right. But we want to customize this list, so we to use Views. Views creates the following two pages:

- http://www.mydomain.me/product-2/tables
- http://www.mydomain.me/product-2/chairs

**Here is my problem. How do we make the taxonomic menu leads us to pages created with Views?**

Currently I get this by changing the URL's menu with jQuery. But this may not be the best way.

Does anyone know how to deal with this duplicity of pages (taxonomy page, and Views page)?

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1) Create a view BLOCK instead of page.

2) Go to manage display of your taxonomy page and disable all fields (you should have an empty page now).

3) In blocks, grab your `view name block` and put it under content area.

Select **Display Only In**.

In the text box, put: `product/*`  (so it will display the view in all `/product` pages).

Comment: I have not tried to do so. But that seems to be an incredibly simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Create a view of taxonomy terms for the specific vocabulary. If you select the path `/taxonomy/term/%` (the `%` is really important) for your view, and select a Contextual Filter to the view for `Content: Has taxonomy ID term`, this will effectively override the path of the default core display for the Taxonomy Term, EVEN if you have defined an alias to the taxonomy term path.

Comment: **I did all the steps that you mention.**
I edit taxonomic term called _Chairs_. I click on _Manage display_ and see the _Term page display_ tab. In _Associated content display_ I select _Views_. In _Views display options_ I select _my-views-name_. In _View's display_ I select _Chairs_. But the frontend never displays the view. The frontend always **shows** the taxonomic page. What am i doing wrong? Furthermore, I realize that the configuration of taxonomic term called "Chairs" applies to "Tables", "Booksellers", etc. What's going on?

Comment: It looks like you went for No Sssweat's solution, so I won't look too deeply into this. My guess is that the module Pathauto (which you are using to create a path alias to your taxonomy terms - the Drupal default is always `/taxonomy/term/[term_id]`) is taking priority over Taxonomy Display. That's why the view is never shown. I would disable the taxonomy alias provided by  Pathauto and try again.

Comment: "...so I won't look too deeply into this...". **No, please continue**. I am very interested to know how to do it with the _Taxonomy display_ module.
"I would disable the taxonomy alias provided by Pathauto". How do I disable an alias? I go to _Settings/Search and metadata/URL Alias_. In the _Operations_ column there are only 2 options: edit and delete. There is no _Disable_ option.

Comment: There is a chance that you actually did not use Pathauto to create aliases. I just realized that Drupal core allows you to create alias manually as well. I did not know that until now.

Comment: OK, more testing here. Scrap 90% of what I said above :) (I deleted some of my comments to avoid confusion of future readers). This is how I made it work. You don't even need Taxonomy Display! Disable it. Simply set the path of your view to `taxonomy/term/%` (exactly like that) and use the Contextual Filter I had in my original answer. Drupal takes care of the rest!!! (Even if you have aliases in the system, Drupal will understand that the view is overriding the default Taxonomy display if you set the path as I just mentioned). This should work. Just edited my answer above to reflect this.

Comment: Notice additional edits to the Contextual Filter to make this solution work

Comment: Ok, still not working. **But there is a new behavior! Which is good!**
I give click to _Chairs_ in taxonomic menu. This does not lead me to taxonomic page. Very good! The problem is that it takes me to a 404 page. The URL is correct and matches a taxonomy (taxonomy/term/12). I mean, **the alias exists**.Then I do not know why appears a 404.

Comment: Hi there. I wish I could help you figure this out. It's hard for me to do more than I've done, and also it's tricky since I don't have access to your full Drupal installation. If I were you I would start some deep debugging, perhaps starting a new Drupal installation and working ONLY with the taxonomy aspects of your system.

Answer (score 0):

With the module [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), you have automatically a default views on this page path  `/taxonomy/term/%`, `/taxonomy/term/%/%/feed`

It's **disabled** by default. Just activate the view and you can modify it as you want.

No need to create special menu or so, it will be effective in the menu too.